# Firebase Sync handling

Tags: angularjs, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have data structure like below:

```
-Company
       |
      -jskdhjJKHh-Yty
        -companyName:CompanyTH

-Employees
   |
  -shdjasjdshy665-333
      |
     -empName:Peter
      |
     -Company
       -jskdhjJKHh-Yty:true
```

Im pushing data of `Employees` like below in `ParentController`:

**Step 1:**

```
var ref=firebase.database().ref("Employees");
var newKey=ref.push({empName:"John"}).key
```

**Setup 2:**

```
var childCompany=ref.child(newKey+'/Company');
childCompany.set(true);
```

**Step 3:**

```
$scope.emplist=$firebaseArray(ref);
```

In `HTML`:

```
<div ng-repeat="emp in emplist" ng-Controller="ChildController">
    <p>{{emp.empName}}</p>
    <p>{{CompanyName}}</p>
</div>
```

In `ChildController`:

```
var companyRef=firebase.database().ref("Company/"+Object.keys($scope.emp.Company)[0]);
$scope.CompanyName=$firebaseObject(companyRef);
```

Problem is :

When `Step 1` executed it sync data to `$scope.emplist` and `ChildController` executed for that `ng-repeat` instance and when code in `ChildController` try to execute line `Object.keys($scope.emp.Company)[0]` it gives error that `Company` is not defined. This error is beacause `Step 2` is not executed and `firebase` sync data after `Step 1`.But when `Step 2` is executes it updates `firebase-database` but `ChildController` does not executes on updatation of `ng-repeat` instance.

One Solution in my mind that somehow Can I stop `Firebase` to sync data until all push queries finish? or any of you guys have any other solution?

One thing to note:

Above mentions steps executes successfully when I run it 2nd time again in same session of application, it is strange that it don't run in first attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your problem correctly, then you might have to change your push logic a bit.

Its always handy to save data in a specific node in Firebase in a single push command. As far as I can see, you're trying to push the data `Employees` node in two steps. Is it really necessary? You can easily push the `empName` and the `childCompany` at once using a single push.

And in your `ChildController`, you need to add a listener to that node from where you're trying to fetch the data using `ref.on`. So that you get a callback after a successful store of the data in your Firebase database.

```
var companyRef=firebase.database().ref("Company/"+Object.keys($scope.emp.Company)[0]);
companyRef.on("value", function(data) {
  // This will be triggered once there's a
  // change in data in the node the reference is referring to
  doSomething();
});
```

**Update**

> then how I can use set(true) within push?

Take a single object containing both `empName` and `childCompany`. Then just use push like this.

```
// Get the firebase reference of your node
var ref = firebase.database().ref("Employees");

// Create an object first. 
var employee = {
  empName: "Peter",
  company: "CompanyTH"
};

// Pass the object that you've prepared earlier here. 
ref.push.set(employee);
```

This is just an example. You can have nested object. The idea is to passing the whole object at once and add a callback on successful save in Firebase. You might think of something like this too.

```
ref.set(employee, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    doSomethingOnError();
  } else {
    doSomethingOnDataSavedSuccessfully();
  }
});
```

You can try building nested classes like this

```
var employee = {
  empName: "Peter",
  Company: {
    companyName: "Name",
    uniqueID: true
  }
};
```

Comment: then how I can use `set(true)` within `push`? Yes its necessary, My Db structure is flatten ,I am saving `Company` reference in `Employee`

Comment: can you tell me

Comment: Please see the update and let me know if that helped.

Comment: im saving Company with reference `CompanyID:true`. but your example saving company data with in Employees

Comment: This is just an example. Please modify it as your needs. Modify the object as you want to store in your database.

Comment: `var employee = {
  empName: "Peter",
  Company/UniqueID: true
};`.... we cannot do this  dear....

Comment: Please see the updated answer. You can try creating nested classes like this.

Comment: it looks better. now im facing error in syntax `Company:{[scope.CompID]:true}`